Need sample config definition for "DefaultParams" as used in web spell checker (wsc.js) for CKEditor 4
I am using CKEditor 4.15
When the user selects from the spell check toolbar item "Check Spelling" a JavaScript error is generated Uncaught ReferenceError: DefaultParams is not defined in wsc.js 5:76.
I tried adding an empty object
DefaultParams = {};

but then I get errors from elements expected on this object.
Is there a sample definition available for DefaultParams?  Should it be defined in the function CKEDITOR.editorConfig(config) or somewhere else?
